# What's the equivalent of this code using array to one using generic lists?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems translating this piece of code:
   `float [,] varname;`

to something using `List<>`

basically i want a way of creating bi-dimensional generic list with that kind of setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write:

```
List<List<float>> list;
```

Take care that in this case each outer list can have different-sized inner list, is not the same as an array..Also the inner-list can be `null`.

for the initialization use:

```
List<List<float>> f = new List<List<float>>();
f.Add(new List<float>());
//add other lists
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a 2D list implementation, but you can achieve somewhat similar behaviour with a "jagged" list, i.e. a list of lists:

```
List<List<float>> varname;
```

It brings some problems though, for example `varname[n]` can be null, or `varname[n][m]` can have `m` out of range for some arrays, etc. You would have to write some more complex accessors to take care of these states. Even the initialization is a bit more complex.

If there's no conceptual issue with using an array, I'd stick with the array.

Comment: maybe i'm complicating things, but i wanted to save some performance, so i decided to do a test using 2D arrays and 2D lists to see if it was worth the effort

Comment: Well, the performance depends heavily on the list/array size changes. If there are no size changes, array wins hands down. If the size(s) may change, you can initialize the lists with an initial size of their internal array